# Нарисовать по формуле. Простой пример, который по сути должен нарисовать прямую, а в результате ничего

Tags: c#, winforms

```
int powera1 = (x - 2);
chart2.Series.Add("Graphics");
chart2.Series["Graphics"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
chart2.Series["Graphics"].Color = Color.Red;
chart2.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

double result = powera1;
chart2.Series["Graphics"].Points.AddY(result);
```

Comment: Вы добавили только _одну_ точку на график. Добавьте ещё хотя бы одну - получится линия.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov.  Да, слегка затупил. А если у нас есть формула ?  double result = Math.Pow(Math.E, powera1);
           
                    chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(result); Оно тоже одну точку нарисует ? По логике

Comment: Вычисляйте значения по формуле в цикле.